# How to search through column A for 60 or 59 characters then highlight row with purple

Tags: vba, excel

The code below is suppose to search for cells in column A that only have 60 or 59 characters and then highlight the row and add a line below. The code will run but will not add any color or add lines, please help

```
Dim k As Range
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim sht As Worksheet

    Set sht = Worksheets.Select
    lastRow = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row   

For Each k In sht.Range("B1:L" & lastRow).Cells
If Len(k.Value) = 60 Or Len(k.Value) = 59 Then
    k.EntireRow.Cells(1).Interior.Color = 24
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    End If
    Exit For

Next k
End With
```

Comment: K is a range not a integer.

Comment: row A ? I thinkk you meant column A.

Comment: @newguy each cell in the first row I believe even though code is looping `B1 to L something` XD

Comment: How do I make sure the worksheet range goes all the way though to the end? should I do sht.Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Cells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding or subtracting rows it is best to loop backwards.

The previous loop was looping through every cell except Column A so it would never return true, thus it was doing nothing.

Try this:

```
Dim k As Long
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim sht As Worksheet

Set sht = ActiveSheet
lastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For k = lastRow To 1 Step -1
    If Len(sht.Cells(k, 1).Value) = 60 Or Len(ht.Cells(k, 1).Value) = 59 Then
        Rows(k).Interior.Color = 24
        Rows(k).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    End If
Next k
```

Comment: Is there anyway to highlight the row that has only 60 or 59 characters? I ran it and the macro completes but I cannot tell if it worked since it does not highlight the line

Comment: @tamarasmith See edit. Replace whole code I made a typo.